# How to use the 'where' option in numpy.multiply?

Tags: numpy

I need to multiply an array (NIR) with a scalar (f) but leaving some values that meet a certain condition intact.

I tried the following:

```
NIR_f = np.multiply(NIR,f,where=NIR!=-28672.0)
```

To check I made:

```
i,j=1119,753
NIR[i][j],NIR_f[i][j]
```

and I got this:

```
(-28672.0, 10058.0)
```

It is assumed that both results should be the same! In that position the condition is not met, therefore the value should remain intact.

Am I using the "where" option wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your array, or a smaller substitute, I can't exactly replicate your problem.  But there are potentially 2 issues

- float testing is not exact, so it might be matching one -28672.0, and not another.
- the `remain intact` assumption is tricky.  `leave the value in the output alone`, but what was it originally, 0's or `NIR` values.

---

Using an integer array to avoid the float issue:

```
In [20]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [21]: arr
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [22]: np.multiply(arr, 10, where=arr!=10)
Out[22]: 
array([[           0,           10,           20,           30],
       [          40,           50,           60,           70],
       [          80,           90, 481036337249,          110]])
In [24]: np.multiply(arr, 10, where=arr!=10)
Out[24]: 
array([[  0,  10,  20,  30],
       [ 40,  50,  60,  70],
       [ 80,  90,   0, 110]])
```

`arr[2,2]` is random.  In effect it started with a `np.empty` array of the right shape and dtype, and filled all values but that one with the multiplication.  To use `where` correctly we need to specify an `out` parameter as well.

```
In [25]: out = np.full(arr.shape,-1)
In [26]: out
Out[26]: 
array([[-1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1]])
In [27]: np.multiply(arr, 10, where=arr!=10, out=out)
Out[27]: 
array([[  0,  10,  20,  30],
       [ 40,  50,  60,  70],
       [ 80,  90,  -1, 110]])
```

The issue of inexact floats comes up often enough that I won't try to illustrate that.

Comment: Hello hpaulj.
I didn't specify `NIR` because it is an extensive array (2400x2400) and the values with problems were in scattered positions. On the other hand, I tried your instructions and ... you're right! By specifying the `out` parameter I get the results I expected.
Thank you very much!